# OnPremise: Sharepoint Hosted App gives 401 unauthorized error while accessing UserProfile Rest Service

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We have an OnPremise Environment for SharePoint 2013. where we have created SharePoint hosted app which calls "`http://<appweburl>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties`" to get current user's data but this gives me 401 unauthorized error.
Notes:

1. I had given read permission to user profile and full control to sitecollection in appmanifest. If I run this app on Office 365 developer site it works fine, but on premise environment it give 401 error.
2. On premise environment when I deploy this app 3 times it prompt for  credential and finally gives the following error

> Message from webpage

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your Web Application is configured to use Claims-Based Application?

Comment: yes, it uses claim based authentication

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 and on-premises farms use different authentication mechanisms for provider-hosted apps. It appears that you haven't properly configured the trust relationship for your app in the on-premises farm. Here are a couple resources that should help you understand the different authentication mechanisms and perform the required configuration.

[Deep dive: SharePoint and Office App Security Model (OAuth & S2S)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC409)

[How to: Create high-trust apps for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ours is SharePoint Hosted App not Provider Hosted App. To make it simple i am deploying my SharePoint hosted app from Visual Studio and it is being trusted properly but after that when it redirects to the default page there i am getting the error. Does it can have any issue with AppDomain. from browser if request "http://<sitecollection>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties" i am getting the data but from app url "http://<app-url>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties" it gives the issue

Comment: Hmmm... that seems odd. The only thing I can think of is that your on-premises farm is not properly configured for Apps. Do you have other Apps running there?

Comment: Yep Rob, I have Provider Hosted hosted with self signed certificate and its running fine without any error. Dont know what to do ?. still struggling.